# Change a single gridline color in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to control the color of specific lines in the panel grid in `ggplots`? I'd like to have a "decorative" line indicate the 0 on the y-axis, using `geom_hline`. You can see from the code and plot below, that just adding `geom_hline` keeps the grey gridlines. I'd like for the line crossing the y-axis to be transparent and the rest of the gridlines to remain grey.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = NULL)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 4, size = 2)+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(size = 2))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, but a hack might be to add 2 `geom_hline`s at that same intercept: one the same color as the background, then the one with the dashed line. Note that the order matters--putting the background-colored one first means it will be drawn below the dashed one

Comment: Brilliant hack! Thanks! Make this an answer.

Comment: The hack above will be much easier, but it's also possible to specify the color for each grid line directly, if you know which one you want to change. `+ theme(panel.grid.major.y =  element_line(size = 2,  color = c("gray92", "gray92", "white", "gray92", "gray92")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `ggplot` layers are drawn in the order they're received, you can draw a `geom_hline` below the dashed one (same size as the gridlines or bigger), make it the same color as the background fill, and it will block out the gridline.

In an easy case, you know the background color (in this case, it's white):

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = NULL) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 2, color = "white") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 4, size = 2) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(size = 2))
```

[image]

To make it more dynamic and match with themes, take the fill of the theme's plot background, and set that as the color:

```r
ggplot(data = NULL) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, size = 2, 
             color = theme_dark()$panel.background$fill) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 4, size = 2) +
  theme_dark() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(size = 2))
```

[image]